# Assigning two intents to a single button

Tags: android, button, android-activity, imageswitcher

So, here's my code (which is working fine).  What I want to do is change the action of the button when `mPosition==messagecount`.  I'm new to Android, so bear with me.  I tried to add a new intent at this point to begin a new `activity` `onSwitch` (Button in xml has `android:onClick="onswitch"`).  Is there a way to do this, or am I just going about it the wrong way?  I currently have a seperate button to begin the activity, but I would like the one button to do both.  Help is greatly appreciated.

```
public void onSwitch(View view) {
    TutorialSwitcher.setBackgroundResource(imageIDs[mPosition]);
    mPosition = (mPosition + 1);
    if(mPosition==messageCount)
        mPosition=0;

}
```

Comment: i think do something like before if Intent i=yourFirstIntent and in if(mPosition==messgeCount){ i=secondIntent}

Comment: You can use the `if-else` condition inside `onClick` method and can control when you want to start which intent.

Answer (score 0):

What actually you want to do with button. Can you explain a bit clearly.
You can use settag for button as per your requirement and when button is clicked use view.gettag() to get the tag. In this way you can make multiple use of the same buttom.
Let me know if you needed something else.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer.so put it inside comments.

Comment: Given one solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an If statement to sort this out try it`

```
if (mPosition == messagecount){
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, newActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define in xml method android:onClick="onswitch" and in your java class onSwitch(View view) - your method onSwitch never has been called. "onswitch" is not equal to "onSwitch" but I hope that it is a gap.

If you want call this method only for one button, will be better if you used onClickListener for this button. Please see example code below:

```
        Button btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            mPosition = (mPosition + 1);
            if (mPosition == messageCount) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class));
                // TODO do action 1.
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class));
                // TODO do something else.
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This worked exactly like I needed it to.  I did not need an "else function", though.  Also, the "onswitch" deal was just a typo on hear, my fault.  Strangely enough, I tried this yesterday, but it didn't work.  I was trying to name the intent and it just kept throwing me errors.  Can you explain why this is?

Comment: Please attach your log from LogCat. Will be very helpful if we can see which kind of errors you have.